# My Best Week, Month, Quarter, Year

Tags: feature-request, jobs, reputation-leagues

I'd like request a way for the Stack Exchange reputation leagues to have a section where it displays "My best..." in the following categories with the perma-link to each. As an example:

- Week ... Dec 11, 2011 - Dec 15, 2011 #187 (Rep: 248) link
- Month ... March 2010 #293 (Rep: 1,409) link
- Quarter ... Q3 2011 #308 (Rep: 2,413) link
- Year ... 2010 #511 (Rep: 9,102) link

This would probably be best suited to display on the Careers 2.0 site, but also a fun feature for members who don't yet have - or don't want - a Careers profile.

This would make it a lot easier that trying to write a query against [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/)
, or paging through results a single period at a time.

Comment: I think it would be nice to have Day as well - both with and without bounties.

Comment: @JonSkeet Absolutely. There's a ton of data that could go into it. If it happens, I could see this becoming a reputation dashboard or scorecard.

Comment: There should obviously be limitations on which users can access what data. I mean we wouldn't want to waste resources caching data for a user who has 150 reputation over 2 years, or for a user who has only been here for a month (gee, I wonder what their best month will be).

Comment: @animuson: Given how little data would actually be required, I suspect it would be simpler to keep it for everyone than to work out how much to record for who, and what to display when it's missing.