# Make the period views of the Users page able to show the previous period (i.e. year 2022) or the last 365 days

Tags: feature-request, statistics, users-page, participation

According to Glorfindel's answer to [How to get the historical data in users Tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305275/289691) it's not possible to use SEDE to get historical voters data due to votes being anonymized.

Please add a way in Reputation, Editors, Voters and Participation tags from the Users page to see data from the previous period.

I.E., when selecting the year and turning on the option to see the data of the previous period. The screenshot was taken on January 2023, it shows the Users > Voters page of Web Applications SE. The idea is to be able to see the Voters of 2022.

[image: Users > Voters]

I'm not asking to replace the current statics but to add the statistics of the entire previous periods. One way to implement this might be to have a toggle button. By default show the current period, clicking the toogle, will show the previous period.

---

Today, during the whole week, including today, Saturday, October 7, 2023, the Week, Month and Quarter views are redundant, showing the same data. This occurs because this week, the first day of the month is the same day that the filter of the three views, October 1, 2023. At other moments, like the start of every quarter, the Month and Quarter will show the same data, and the first quarter will be the same as the year view.

This happens on the tabs of the Users page

- Reputation
- Editors
- Voters
- Participation (since 2022, only on per-child metas)

Another option instead of showing the data of the previous period could be to change the filtering, instead of using a fixed date, show the last 7, 30, 90, and 365 days respectively.

Related

- [My Best Week, Month, Quarter, Year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116299/289691)
- [How is meta participation calculated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145151/289691)
- [Discrepancy in Stats for StackOverflow's Top Users by Week, Month, Quarter, or Year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260052/289691)
- [How to see all of top x% this year / quarter / month / week / overall?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271158/289691)

Comment: @toolic I'm not asking to replace the current statics but to add the statistics of the entire previous periods. One one to implemt this might be to have to toggle button. By default show the current period, clicking the toogle, show the previous period.